# Azure Backup Center - SQL in Azure VM - Backup Alerts for monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-backup-vault

In Azure Backup Center, we have set up SQL in Azure VM backup jobs for our sql databases. I can see the backup jobs in the backup center. Also in the Recovery Services vault I find the jobs under Backup Items - Sql in Azure VM.
In Azure Monitor - Activity log, I only get (success and/or failure) information about the Azure Virtual machines backup. Succes information about the SQL jobs can't be found, unless we start the job manually.

Is there a way to get success information about SQL backup jobs in monitor?
Maybe through Diagnostic setting or Log Analytics workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Azure Monitor does provide success information for [SQL backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/manage-monitor-sql-database-backup) jobs.

To obtain success information regarding SQL backup jobs in Azure Monitor you can use the [Diagnostic Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics) or Log Analytics workspace.

[image]
It may helps refer this [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/backup/backup-azure-monitoring-use-azuremonitor.md)  and use this query as mentioned in document.

- All successful SQL log backup jobs

```
   AddonAzureBackupJobs
      | where JobOperation=="Backup" and JobOperationSubType=="Log"
      | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated,*) by JobUniqueId
      | where JobStatus=="Completed"
      | join kind=inner
      (
          CoreAzureBackup
          | where OperationName == "BackupItem"
          | where BackupItemType=="SQLDataBase" and BackupManagementType=="AzureWorkload"
          | distinct BackupItemUniqueId, BackupItemFriendlyName
      )
      on BackupItemUniqueId
```